# ASP.NET: Model validation error - bad request

Tags: asp.net, .net, validation, model

I have to analyze and find which is the error in the following form (it's not my code):

[image]

I bet the code is .NET

and I see that the problem lies in the form field Indirizzo (address), which must contain the street name, 
but it looks like it is connected with the other address fields (provence, city, zip code, street number).

I cannot analyze the error returned by the server, I write it clearly here:

> Errore EGON: The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request.
>
> at SSOService.Models.EgonModel.Validate(String DPT, String CNL, String
>   ZIP, String TPM, String ADDR, String CIV, EgonConfiguration conf) in
>   D:\Progetti\Nordcom\SSOSolution\trunk\SSOService\Models\EgonModel.cs:line
>   65 at
>   SSOService.Models.Validations.ValidateAddressEgon_internal(EnTipoIndirizzo
>   tipoIndirizzo, String indirizzo, String civico, String cap, String
>   provinciaStr, String cittaStr, String toponimoStr, Controller
>   controller, String chiaveToponimo, String chiaveIndirizzo, String
>   chiaveCivico, String chiaveCap, String chiaveComune, String
>   chiaveProvincia, String descrizioneIndirizzo) in
>   D:\Progetti\Nordcom\SSOSolution\trunk\SSOService\Models\Validations.cs:line
>   1171

What is it indicating?

Comment: Can you show your EgonModel.cs file? The issue is on line 65 :)

Comment: Actually I cannot, I was not me that wrote my code. So I am trying to guess which kind of error was made by the person who wrote it.

Comment: It fails with a 400 status so i suspect one of the parameters is causing an issue, malformed syntax potentially?. All this is guess work of course without seeing the code...

Comment: looks like the "standardization" of the address has failed, as I see that the code is probably using an API coming from this service: https://www.egon.com/it/soluzioni/normalizzazione-indirizzi
as it says "error EGON"